# Updating mysql table field only when condition is met

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have this query:

```
UPDATE orders SET tracking = '$trackingnumber', tracking_timestamp = NOW() 
WHERE comment like '%$ordernumber%'
```

Is it possible to update tracking_timestamp ONLY if the value of the field is 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Comment: It should always update the tracking column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE`

```
UPDATE orders 
SET tracking = '$trackingnumber',
 tracking_timestamp = CASE 
WHEN tracking_timestamp='0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
THEN NOW() 
ELSE tracking_timestamp
 END
WHERE comment like '%$ordernumber%'
```

Comment: and I guess you mean '$tracking_timestamp' where you said tracking_timestamp?

Comment: @KristianRafteseth according to your question update `tracking_timestamp` if `tracking_timestamp` have `0000-00-00 00:00:00` right ? there is no `$tracking_timestamp` variable in your question so i provided the case condition on field not variable

Comment: ah my bad, abit too fast here.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth you can still update your question :)

Comment: yeah. is it possible to skip the ELSE clause here by the way?

Comment: Yes you can skip like `CASE WHEN tracking_timestamp='0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN NOW() END`

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
UPDATE orders 
SET tracking = '$trackingnumber', 
tracking_timestamp = IF (tracking_timestamp='0000-00-00 00:00:00',NOW(),'0000-00-00 00:00:00') 
WHERE COMMENT LIKE '%$ordernumber%'
```